# wordpress loop - style 1st post differently to the following (side loop get_posts())

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, count

In my wordpress theme, I want to add in the footer a side loop to fetch the latest posts.
the first post of this loop displays thumb pix, title, and post preview..
the 5 following only displays the title/link.

Since I already use the regular `<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`
in the main div, I have to use a side loop based on get_posts()

this is what I want to get, but it's not working:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=6&showposts=5'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=6&numberposts=5'); 
$count = count($posts);
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php if ($count < 2) : ?>

        /// code for the 1st post (thumb etc..)

    <?php else : ?>

           /// code for the 4 following post (links to posts only)          

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I know how to add count/condition for the regular wordpress loop but not with the get_posts() function.

Can you please help me achieving that ?

Thanks in advance ;)

---

edit: the solution :

Ok I used the 'offset' argument to achieve that:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=2&offset=0'); 
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="footernews-thumb">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(thumbnail); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</a>

<h2 class="footernews-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="footernews-preview"><?php the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 20); ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>        

<?php $posts = get_posts('numberposts=3&offset=1'); 
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>                      
<h2 class="footernews-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>                        
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Since the "loop" is not really a loop, I decided to avoid counting occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a simple incrementing check as such....

```
<?php query_posts('cat=6&showposts=5'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=6&numberposts=5'); 
$i = 1;
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php if ($i == 1) : ?>

    /// code for the 1st post (thumb etc..)

<?php else : ?>

       /// code for the 4 following post (links to posts only)          

<?php endif; ?>
<?php ++$i;
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($i); ?>
```

This will then only give you the additional output for the first iteration, after that it will just keep going using the lesser code.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `$count` to the number of posts you're getting (5) so it will NEVER be less than 2.

You need to change it to this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=6&showposts=5'); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=6&numberposts=5'); 
$first = true;
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
    <?php if ($first) : ?>

        /// code for the 1st post (thumb etc..)
        <?php $first = false; ?>
    <?php else : ?>

           /// code for the 4 following post (links to posts only)          

    <?php endif;?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: idrumgood, thank you so much! It's lighter than repeating the query twice with an offset in the arguments. perfect ;)